# Quartic (degree 4) polynomial complex number problem

Tags: polynomials, induction, roots

Can you find a quartic (degree 4) polynomial $p(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ with real coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ whose roots are precisely $x=5$, $x=-2$, $x=3$ and $x=1+i$ ?

Guys please help I've been pondering this question for hours and still can't find it :S

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you know about the complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients?

Comment: Can you give me any hint? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. With real coefficients, if some complex number $\beta$ is a root, then so is $\bar{\beta}$

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, since the product of the roots is a complex non-real number, which equals the polynomial's free coefficient divided by the main one:

$$(-2)\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot(1+i)=30+i\in\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$$

If $\,a\,,\,e\in\Bbb R\,$, then also $\,e/a\in\Bbb R\,$